# Sorry for saying this, but is the "moderator election" really necessary?

Tags: discussion

I mean, I have no grudge against any moderators here, or mostly anywhere, but I chose the first pick only because I know him well (not so well in reality).

So is choosing someone as No1, or No2, or No3 really fair? I mean, What kind of feeling might the moderators who fell in No3 feel like? (only because, personally speaking, I did not know him well?)

I think this might be the only community where the moderators are not the ones answering ELLs. So what's the point in the elections?

Comment: It was necessary because the existing team felt the need for more hands to help. As the site grows busier and bigger, we need more moderators to handle things. The mod position is not a luxurious pendant or a medal, and people who have done enough for the community to be trusted with such chores are elected.

Comment: With very few exceptions, no one here really knows anyone well; see [**this link.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Internet_dog.jpg#/media/File:Internet_dog.jpg)

Comment: @DEAD I mean, the matter in question is, I do not remember if I have ever encountered any "moderators" when anybody answer to my questions....

Comment: Kentaro moderators aren't supposed to be good at answering. They're supposed to be good at moderating stuff, and that would be editing, commenting, reviewing, closing etc. Most of that stuff can be dug, but it's usually behind the scenes.

Comment: See, look at the site of my mother tongue. There sometimes the "move" stops, and there remain question here and there and at such time "moderators" often give answer so that they are trying ( or at least it looks like to me ) to "invigorate" the site...

Comment: That's not part of their job as a moderator, but just as a regular user. Everyone can answer unanswered questions if they want to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The moderator election was necessary to get more people in place to do work that needs to be done (such as responding to flags and dealing with any spam or offensive content that isn't deleted through flags).

It makes sense to put the person you know best as your first choice because you can be confident that this person will be a good moderator. But that doesn't mean you're judging that the other people would be bad moderators; it sounds like you just don't know. That isn't a reason for them to feel bad.

I didn't vote for *anybody* this election because even though I sometimes browse this site, I didn't think I was active enough to be familiar with all the candidates and their patterns of behavior here.

Comment: +1 for last pgh.

Comment: Thank you. 
 

>The moderator election was necessary to get more people in place to do work that needs to be done. Agreed to the maximum with many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Them's the breaks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/them%27s_the_breaks). We signed up to see which of us would be chosen to do the best job moderating and representing the community; if the site voters don't know one of us well enough to be confident voting for them, whose fault is that?

Note that no one can see who you voted for, so there's no way for someone to feel hurt that you put them third.

Also note that all our existing moderators *do* answer questions from time to time, especially J.R.

Comment: I'd like to add: MaulikV♦ _asks_ a lot of [good questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3187/maulik-v?tab=badges&sort=recent), too!