# Why is "somebody" showing the link to the Monica controversy?

Tags: discussion

On the front page of the ELL, (Q&A), I see a link to [**the recent update on Monica issue**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio?cb=1)

J.R. and ColleenV expressed their resignation, am I correct?

Then why don't other moderators or any kind of hidden pro-monica members show us the next moderators election? And what for the link to the above mentioned statement by Sara Chipps is on the front page of the ELL?

Sara says,

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

If I take her comment literally, I think Ms. Cellio is not satisfied. Who is issuing the link to the content of Meta?

This is a rare case and you donated to Monica like 20,000 dollars and your inactivity infuriates me. (If you decided to resign, go ahead. Already nearly 3months passed.) You are writing your post with anger and hate, and it conducts through me emotionally. **JUST DO IT OR DO NOT ANYTHING, PLEASE**

Comment: `You think the position of the moderator is voluntary and now you demand it was a priviledge and reinstate? Come on guys, you are already contradicting there.`  The person who's contradicting themself is the one whose username asks people to donate to Monica's fund  :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah I wrongly changed my name before I knew the truth. I so much regret I am considering or rather ready to leave here which is totally in mess.

Comment: I am afraid this is again a post that is pretty garbled and not asking for information - or rather using one sort-of question (how was a Meta post featured) to rant about a completely separate topic. **Please stop this behavior.** And as you seem very uniformed about the mechanisms, just one little detail: When a moderator resigns, it may take a while for that to be actually be implemented in the system (remember: manual process!), and there’s little said moderator can do apart from badgering the CMs, which a good moderator, who in the past took their responsibility seriously, likely won’t do.

Comment: For the record, I have **not** resigned (although I did publicly announce that I would be a lot less involved than I had been over the past several years).

Answer (score 12):

A post on the global, SE meta site, https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (which is not the same as ELL's meta, https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/, the site you've posted this question on) becomes featured on **every** Stack Exchange site (ELL.SE, Stack Overflow, Super User, Japanese.SE, etc.) when a moderator tags it with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

You can see if you scroll down [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/340906/revisions) that user Sara Chipps edited the post to include the tag, and thereby made the question featured across the Stack Exchange network.

As an aside, if the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is used to tag a particular ELL meta post, the post becomes featured, and appears in the same side bar on ELL's main site, https://ell.stackexchange.com/ (but it doesn't show up on other sites, such as Stack Overflow). This works the same way with every non-global meta site.

---

Users ColleenV and J.R. indeed appear to have decided to distance themselves from their moderating roles and duties. They have for all intents and purposes **resigned** as moderators. Their diamonds (♦), together with their moderating abilities, may or may not disappear, but those are a mere formality. The post you're talking about, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio), has nothing to do with them directly either.

A lot of people have expressed their frustration with the circumstances surrounding user Monica Cellio's dismissal as a moderator, and that post seems to be an attempt at clarifying and making public the company's stance and decisions they've taken as concerns the matter.

I suggest you not take any of that personally, and when the time for moderator elections comes, we'll all be notified.

Comment: Please do not delete. The OP has a habit of posting questions which are thinly disguised attacks on the resigned moderators, Colleen and J.R. only to find that their point of view and understanding of the present situation is misguided, which then attracts somes downvotes. The OP realizes he has public opinion against them, or has made false assumptions, and promptly deletes the posts. Not this time!

Comment: @Kentaro I'm satisfied with the answer, and I don't see anyone objecting to it, so I have no reason to delete it. If someone else has a question similar to yours, perhaps they'll find this answer useful. Don't worry about this stuff.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thinly disguised? I **openly** made a fire in the former question? (which probably CollenV deleted **not** me.) Well, then it's fine. I'm just appalled you guys and ladies are throwing anger stone in the air and thinking throwing more stones improves the situation. Fine. Continue the ineffective battle.

Comment: Kentaro the angry person in the room, is you. You are always upset over something, and it's usually about the poor reception your meta posts receive. I suggested a feature request for ELL and all you did was moan about its impracticability. Then you changed your mind, as you appear to do fairly frequently.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am **always** upset over what? Your hideous anger at MSE over Monica issue can be transmitted to me which makes me angry too. You think the position of the moderator is voluntary and now you demand it was a priviledge and reinstate? Come on guys, you are already contradicting there.

Comment: @Kentaro - You are always upset over what? Oh, things like [moderator intervention](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5075), [moderator elections](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3201), [undeleted comments](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5031), [deleted comments](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4976), [other comments](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4765), and so forth. (Maybe these questions were genuine inquiries, not rants, but you've had a history of throwing a lot of not-so-positive accusations around meta.)

Comment: @J.R. not to mention Kentaro's deleted posts, some of which were self-deleted.